# Python 3 Django - middleware for some request

Tags: python, django

I created a middleware which contain lot of functions to check something before getting the view.
And i added the middleware to the setting.py, but it is for all requests.
So, how can i make the middleware work for some requests, not all?

Answer (score 0):

The first check you need to do in your middleware is the request logic that will tell you which request should go through all your functions and which request shouldn't. That's it.

Just write a function that will check whether this request is the correct request to go through middleware or not. If not, then just skip the middleware. I'm confused as to whether you are asking for the specific code or not.